# Finding unknown coordinates using vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, pythagorean-triples

I need some help in understanding how to complete my assignment. Supposedly there's a cube 'sunk in the ground'(kind of like the Rubik's cube in the museum of Melbourne) with coordinates A,A',B,B',C,C', and D,D' of which we know only 3 coordinates: B = (3, 23, 12), B' = (2, 20, 0), D = (30, 14, 12). (the ' means the coordinate is the bottom coordinate directly below the the letter without the ') (The bottom coordinates are at the bottom of the cube that is above the ground, not the entire cube)

Visuals: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gib8N.jpg

I know how to calculate the various side lengths using vector methods i.e

$ B-B' = |BB'|$ and $|BB'|^2+|DB|^2 = |BD|^2 $

but I'm completely lost when it comes to calculating the coordinates, and any help regarding how to understand the topic would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: If we can judge by the [picture](https://www.flickr.com/photos/iprahin/8098707484) B and D, being the same height, must be adjacent.   It doesn't look like there are two opposite corners above the ground at the same height.  That would make the side of the cube $9\sqrt{10}$.  I don't know if it's allowed to make the inference in the first comment, though.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I got the lengths: |BB'|= 12.4 and |DB| = 28.46, which makes |DB'| = 31.04 the only thing I have trouble with are calculating the coordinates

Answer (score 1):

The line through $B$ and $B'$ extends to a corner buried in the ground.  Let's call the buried corner $B_0$.  The distance from $B$ to $B_0$ is $\overline{BD}$.  Once you know $B_0$, you know three corners of the cube. Now for example, the line $BC$ is perpendicular to both $B'B$ and $BD$ so you can find its direction using cross product.  You already know it's length.

Then you know $\vec{BA}=\vec{BC}+\vec{BD}$ so you can find $A$.  Now you know all the top vertices, and you also know $v=\vec{BB_0}$.  Adding $v$ in turn to $A, C, D$ will give $A',C',D'$.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but is it possibe BB' is actually not buried in the ground? My apologies for not showing it before, but this is the pic for visuals: https://imgur.com/a/oU0O2HG